# Raspberry Pi TCP socket - [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, udp, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi 3 set up as an access point or as a hotspot in other words ([raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)). I connect to this from a windows 10 pc, with ip address of `192.168.0.10`. I am able to send and receive udp packets, also the mentioned ip address can be pinged. But if i try tcp packets (from another python script, from another port), the i always get `errno 99`. The following simple script works on my pc (with local ip), but not on my raspberry:

```py
import socket
snap1 = bytes([0x00, 0x00, 0x56, 0x45, 0x74, 0x44, 0x76 ]) # some data to send
sockT = socket.socket()
sockT.bind(("192.168.0.10", 5008)) #((tcpIpSend, tcpPortSend))
sockT.listen(5)
#sockT.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sockTconn, addr = sockT.accept()
print('Connection estabilished! ', addr)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sockTconn.send(snap1) # TCP
conn.close()
```

If you have any clue please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `192.168.0.10` works on your PC, it must be a local address of your PC, *ergo* it cannot possibly be a local IP address of your Raspberry, *ergo* your Rasperry cannot bind to it.

Use `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks, but, what i ment was client and server on the same pc, so in this case it worked with `localhost` or with `127.0.0.1`. I tried `0.0.0.0`, it did not produce the errno 99, but did not connected either.

Comment: _additional info:_ on my pc the result of `netsh interface ip show addresses "Wi-Fi"` is
`Configuration for interface "Wi-Fi"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           192.168.0.10
    Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.0.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.0.1
    Gateway Metric:                       0
    InterfaceMetric:                      55
`
So i think the proper ip should be `192.168.0.10`

Comment: Ok now it, its working and your suggestion (`0.0.0.0`) was basically correct. The problem was on the pc side, not on the pi side as i suspected.
On the pc side i used the wrong ip, i had a misconception that i have to use the same ip both side, but of course on the pc side the remote port is needed. 
So thank you, i accepted your answer.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. You should use 0.0.0.0 when binding servers unless you really know what the hell you're doing.